# Quantum entangled particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Do we understand why particles are paired with specific other ones? Were they born together or existed right next to one another at another time?  Can they pick (entangle) with new ones? Do we have any science to understand why it's even real?

Comment: What particles? Electrons and protons in hydrogen? That's caused by the electromagnetic force. Quarks inside the proton? That's caused by the color force. The necessary theory to understand this in detail is quantum field theory. Yes, we do understand much of this in detail. What we do not understand is why the vacuum has the specific structure that it has. How that structure works, however, is pretty well understood.

Comment: Vaccume structure ? Like a Higgs field ? I thought Higgs was not technically a vaccume field. But mass comes from the field surrounding the particles and as they release z bosons while changing directions, this boson field is what gives mass. Not the vaccume structure, if that's how I am suppose to understand. I did not know what particles are proved to be entangled. Can't all of them be?

Comment: The standard model is not one field, it's all of them. You can't take it apart and the Higgs is just as much vacuum as the rest. Mass is simply a dispersion relation. Most of the mass in the universe is dark matter, then comes relativistic binding energy in nucleons and then comes a sub-1% contribution from the Higgs, if I am not mistaken. Entanglement is mostly a matter of what you know (or don't know) about your quantum experiment. Nature doesn't play some special entanglement game just to play cute with physicists. If you want to make that into "everything is entangled" is up to you.

Comment: I mean quantum particles of all types. I guess it's pointless if a proton is entangled all protons should be. I was incorrectly thinking of Atoms.  I see what you mean by fields are all together. If I don't explain it well I hope you get it anyway :)

Comment: And by mass I usually refer to electrons and photons going full speed.

Comment: But by entangled, I assume if you have an electron randomly plucked from something where does its get a partner particle, or does it have it somewhere. Isn't that how entangled information is observed.  With specific pairs?

Comment: Entanglement is pretty much like gravity. Does Earth's orbit depend on every hydrogen atom in Andromeda? Yes, if one takes Newtonian mechanics seriously. Does it matter? No, of course not. I would look at it the same way in field theory. If one can separate an observed effect as being, mostly, influenced by one thing or two, that's good physics. That everything depends on everything else... that's completely useless. Why do we need the Higgs? Mostly to sort out the theory of the electroweak force. Beyond that it's probably not particularly fundamental.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. I like how you used a gravity analogy. I was trying to be too specific I see.